# Why ldap user on ldap client must have root ldap password in his config?

Tags: openldap

My Ldap  conf has permiss for client  user Acl to see ,modif auth his attr so why I need to have on clienta PC root pass or other specjal account to bind like binddn ,rootdn?Can somebody explain this proces?.

Answer (score 1):

You **do not configure the *root* account** (or any other highly privileged credentials)  in LDAP clients.

You may need ***a regular user*** account (or rather a service account and not a person's username and password ) to functions as a [***BindDN***](https://serverfault.com/q/616698/37681) when your LDAP directory server does not allow anonymous connections and/or anonymous operations.